# Why does Typescript think the symbol 'name' always exists?

Tags: typescript

I've noticed mistakes in my Typescript being accepted by the compiler when I've written `name` when I meant to write `someObject.name`.

As a test, I tried compiling a single file containing only `console.log(name)` and tsc accepts it. Does Typescript have some global symbols defined?

I'm using Typescript 2.8.1 and have no global packages installed except NPM itself and Typescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a (default) lib for EcmaScript standard, say ES2016. This lib is called "lib.es2016.full.d.ts" (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2016.full.d.ts) and it contains the "name" declaration.

In your editor (if it's not just notepad, but Visual Studio Code for example) you could select "Go to definition" from context menu. Or you could hover above "name" and see, which type "name" actually is (it's "never" and const).

This had been done to restrict access to global (Window) name property:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1351
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9850

Comment: Thanks - I should have thought to look up the definition in VSCode. The issues links are really useful too. I've now added `"lib": ["esnext"]` to my tsconfig.json, so that Typescript now picks up my incorrect use of `name`.